# How to override class_method in rails model concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport-concern

How does one override a class method defined in a model concern?

This is a bit tricky since you’re not really overriding a class method right? Because it’s using the concern api of definining class methods in the `class_methods` block.

so say I have a concern that looks like this:

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def do_something
       #some code
    end
  end

end
```

In model.. how would I override that method so that I could call it like we do with super when using inheritance? So in my model I’d like to go:

```
def self.do_something
  #call module do_something
end
```

?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

If you've `include`d `MyConcern` in the model that defines `self.do_something`, you should just be able to use `super`:

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def do_something
      puts "I'm do_something in the concern"
    end
  end
end

class UsesMyConcern < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyConcern

  def self.do_something
    super
  end
end

UsesMyConcern.do_something
# => "I'm do_something in the concern"
```

If you haven't or don't want to `include MyConcern` in the model and you want to invoke `do_something` on the module without creating any intermediary objects, you can change your model to:

```
class UsesMyConcern < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.do_something                
    MyConcern::ClassMethods.instance_method(:do_something).bind(self).call
  end
end

UsesMyConcern.do_something
# => "I'm do_something in the concern"
```

[`ActiveSupport::Concern.class_methods`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb#L134) defines a `ClassMethods` module in the concern if there isn't one already, and that's where we can find the `do_something` method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply call the module's method: `MyConcern.do_something`?

I'm not sure if there's an easy of doing `super` for modules (though I can see why that may be useful).

The next best solution could be doing something like calling `#included_modules` and manually iterating with `#responds_to?`:

```
def self.do_something
  self.super_module(__method__)
end

def self.super_module(method)
  self.included_modules.find { |m| m.responds_to? method }.public_send(method)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The old way using `alias_method_chain`: https://ernie.io/2011/02/03/when-to-use-alias_method_chain/

The new way (requires > ruby 2.0.0) you really should use this, as there will be a DEPRECATION WARNING when using it in rails 5.0: 
http://paweljaniak.co.za/2014/09/30/understanding-ruby-module-prepend-and-include/

Comment: @reven that's a cool post, really useful actually... but doesn't answer the question.